# Consider a Group $G$ of order $20$ such that $G=Aut$($Z_{25},+) \cong (U_{25}, \cdot)$. Analyze the Sylow subgroups in G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G=Aut$($Z_{25},+) \cong (U_{25}, \cdot)$

I know that there is **one** 5-Sylow subgroup and number of $2-Sylow$ subgroups is either $1$ or $5$.

(a) How do I decide whether the number of distinct 2-Sylow subgroups is $1$ or $5$.

(b) I need to show an explicit subgroup in G of each Sylow type;listing its elements in $U_{25}$.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $G$ is cyclic, what does that tell you about the subgroup structure of $G$?  If you know all the subgroups, then you'll know the Sylow ones.

Comment: So if i can calculate which elements in $U_{20}$ have order 5 (for the 5-Sylow subgroup) and which element has order 4 (for the 2-Sylow subgroup) then the subgroups generated by these elements are the Sylow subgroups. Is that right?

Comment: Well, more to the point, if $G$ is cyclic, then there exists a *unique* subgroup of $G$ for every divisor of the order.  This is what you were getting at, but with the observation that all elements of order $d$ generate the *same subgroup*.

Answer (score 3):

The group of units mod $25$ is cyclic, since $25 = 5^2$ is a power of an odd prime. All subgroups of a cyclic group are normal and themselves cyclic.

Since they are normal, there is exactly one $p$-Sylow subgroup for each prime $p$ dividing the order (so for $p=2$ and $p=5$).

And since all subgroups are cyclic, in particular the $2$-Sylow and the $5$-Sylow are cyclic (or orders $4$ and $5$ respectively).